# Content transfer to iPad through a Java web service

Tags: web-services, ipad, attachment

We are develpoing iPad application which should be download the contents (PDF, MP4, PPT) from server. For that we are develpoing a webservice to transfer the content. The size of the content is around 50 to 100 MB

I need some clarification for the following

1. As of my understanding, It is not possible to send the large contents as SOAP attachment.
2. If I make the content as web URL and transfer to iPad, the iPad can hit the URL and download the content.

What the main difference of the above solutions?

What would be the best approach for my requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I would avoid a SOAP service if possible, as you will spend unnecessary time dealing with the SOAP wrappers.  If you do need to use it, you can use a project such as wsdl2objc to generate the Objective C source.  I would advise using a REST based service instead.
2. Yes, the iPad can hit a URL and download content.  You might be better served by downloading it in pieces instead of a huge 50-100MB download (ie, download each file individually).

Comment: Thanks Robert, What is the difference between webservice transfer and web url transfer? If you provide technical explanation it will be very helpful.

Comment: I don't follow your question.  All you need on the server side is an endpoint, this can be a SOAP webservice, a WCF service, or a simple .aspx or .jsp page that streams back the appropriate content.  I would advise keeping it simple, and create a REST request to a .jsp or .aspx instead of a more formal SOAP web service.